# web user control value set in aspx page

Tags: c#, .net, ascx

Is this possible, I have some C# code that adds web user control onto aspx page see below:

```
 UserControl myUserControl;
 myUserControl = (UserControl)LoadControl("../TempLayouts/LayoutSize.ascx");
 PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myUserControl);
```

On my ascx i have the following code:

```
private int Edit_Mode = 0;
public int Get_EditMode
{
    get { return Edit_Mode; }
    set { Edit_Mode = value; }
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ if(Edit_Mode == 1)//do something}
```

How can I set Edit_Mode value to 1 when calling the web user control in code above, Attributes?

This this possible without casting ?

Answer (score 2):

You need add a class reference in your aspx file, something like this:

```
<%@ Reference Control="../TempLayouts/LayoutSize.ascx" %>
```

Then, in your aspx.cs file add something like this:

```
ASP.LayoutSize_ascx myUserControl;
myUserControl = (ASP.LayoutSize_ascx)LoadControl("../TempLayouts/LayoutSize.ascx");
myUserControl.Edit_Mode = 1;
```

You need check the class name of your control.

Comment: Why you don't want to use casting?

Answer (score 1):

```
 //.aspx
 Control c = Page.LoadControl("LayoutSize.ascx");
 c.GetType().GetProperty("Get_Editor_Mode").SetValue(c, True, null);




//.ascx
    private bool Editor_Mode = false;
    public bool Get_Editor_Mode
    {
        get { return Editor_Mode; }
        set { Editor_Mode = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to your specific control type instead of `(UserControl)`.  That way you can set the properties of your user control before you add it to the page.

Comment: Can't cast the webcontrol as it could be different webcontrol

Comment: Would the "different webcontrol" also have an Edit_Mode property?